# Converting XML to JSON in mule

Tags: mule, mule-component

I have converted HL7 message to XML and I want to convert this XML to JSON. I am using XML to JSON connector. But somehow it is showing me a warning saying

Failed to parse MSH segment. Defaulting to US-ASCII
ca.uhn.hl7v2.HL7Exception: Message encoding is not recognized

Below is my configuration xml

```
<hl7:endpoint host="localhost" port="50609" name="HL7_MLLP" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="HL7 MLLP"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer name="Object_to_JSON" doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <flow name="wsconsumerFlow">
        <hl7:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="50609" tracking:enable-default-events="true" responseTimeout="10000"  doc:name="HL7 MLLP" metadata:id="1c7409bf-e286-4e3d-8e48-3dea6888f554" />
        <hl7:hl7-encoding-transformer hl7Encoding="XML" validation="WEAK" metadata:id="1b0e4ffa-cb7c-4a40-a84d-f11208d5e586" doc:name="HL7 Encoding Transformer"/>
        <json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XML to JSON"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <hl7:exception-strategy doc:name="HL7 Exception Strategy"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Below is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ADT_A01 xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v2xml">
   <MSH>
      <MSH.1>|</MSH.1>
      <MSH.2>^~\&amp;</MSH.2>
      <MSH.7>20161024111855.78-0400</MSH.7>
      <MSH.9>
         <MSG.1>ADT</MSG.1>
         <MSG.2>A01</MSG.2>
         <MSG.3>ADT_A01</MSG.3>
      </MSH.9>
      <MSH.10>201</MSH.10>
      <MSH.11>
         <PT.1>T</PT.1>
      </MSH.11>
      <MSH.12>
         <VID.1>2.6</VID.1>
      </MSH.12>
   </MSH>
   <EVN>
      <EVN.1>A01-</EVN.1>
      <EVN.2>198808181123</EVN.2>
   </EVN>
   <PID>
      <PID.3>
         <CX.1>PATID1234</CX.1>
         <CX.2>5</CX.2>
         <CX.3>M11</CX.3>
      </PID.3>
      <PID.5>
         <XPN.1>
            <FN.1>JONES</FN.1>
         </XPN.1>
         <XPN.2>WILLIAM</XPN.2>
         <XPN.3>A</XPN.3>
         <XPN.4>III</XPN.4>
      </PID.5>
      <PID.7>19610615</PID.7>
      <PID.8>M-</PID.8>
      <PID.10>
         <CWE.1>2106-3</CWE.1>
      </PID.10>
      <PID.11>
         <XAD.1>
            <SAD.1>1200 N ELM STREET</SAD.1>
         </XAD.1>
         <XAD.3>GREENSBORO</XAD.3>
         <XAD.4>NC</XAD.4>
         <XAD.5>27401-1020</XAD.5>
      </PID.11>
      <PID.12>GL</PID.12>
      <PID.13>
         <XTN.1>(919)379-1212</XTN.1>
      </PID.13>
      <PID.14>
         <XTN.1>(919)271-3434</XTN.1>
      </PID.14>
      <PID.14>
         <XTN.1>(919)277-3114</XTN.1>
      </PID.14>
      <PID.16>
         <CWE.1>S</CWE.1>
      </PID.16>
      <PID.18>
         <CX.1>PATID12345001</CX.1>
         <CX.2>2</CX.2>
         <CX.3>M10</CX.3>
      </PID.18>
      <PID.19>123456789</PID.19>
      <PID.20>
         <DLN.1>9-87654</DLN.1>
         <DLN.2>NC</DLN.2>
      </PID.20>
   </PID>
   <NK1>
      <NK1.1>1</NK1.1>
      <NK1.2>
         <XPN.1>
            <FN.1>JONES</FN.1>
         </XPN.1>
         <XPN.2>BARBARA</XPN.2>
         <XPN.3>K</XPN.3>
      </NK1.2>
      <NK1.3>
         <CWE.1>SPO</CWE.1>
      </NK1.3>
      <NK1.8>20011105</NK1.8>
   </NK1>
   <NK1>
      <NK1.1>1</NK1.1>
      <NK1.2>
         <XPN.1>
            <FN.1>JONES</FN.1>
         </XPN.1>
         <XPN.2>MICHAEL</XPN.2>
         <XPN.3>A</XPN.3>
      </NK1.2>
      <NK1.3>
         <CWE.1>FTH</CWE.1>
      </NK1.3>
   </NK1>
   <PV1>
      <PV1.1>1</PV1.1>
      <PV1.2>I</PV1.2>
      <PV1.3>
         <PL.1>2000</PL.1>
         <PL.2>2012</PL.2>
         <PL.3>01</PL.3>
      </PV1.3>
      <PV1.7>
         <XCN.1>004777</XCN.1>
         <XCN.2>
            <FN.1>LEBAUER</FN.1>
         </XCN.2>
         <XCN.3>SIDNEY</XCN.3>
         <XCN.4>J.</XCN.4>
      </PV1.7>
      <PV1.10>SUR</PV1.10>
      <PV1.12>-</PV1.12>
      <PV1.14>1</PV1.14>
      <PV1.15>A0-</PV1.15>
   </PV1>
   <AL1>
      <AL1.1>1</AL1.1>
      <AL1.3>
         <CWE.2>PENICILLIN</CWE.2>
      </AL1.3>
      <AL1.5>PRODUCES HIVES</AL1.5>
      <AL1.5>RASH</AL1.5>
   </AL1>
   <AL1>
      <AL1.1>2</AL1.1>
      <AL1.3>
         <CWE.2>CAT DANDER</CWE.2>
      </AL1.3>
   </AL1>
   <DG1>
      <DG1.1>001</DG1.1>
      <DG1.2>I9</DG1.2>
      <DG1.3>
         <CWE.1>1550</CWE.1>
      </DG1.3>
      <DG1.4>MAL NEO LIVER, PRIMARY</DG1.4>
      <DG1.5>19880501103005</DG1.5>
      <DG1.6>F</DG1.6>
   </DG1>
   <ADT_A01.PROCEDURE>
      <PR1>
         <PR1.1>2234</PR1.1>
         <PR1.2>M11</PR1.2>
         <PR1.3>
            <CNE.1>111</CNE.1>
            <CNE.2>CODE151</CNE.2>
         </PR1.3>
         <PR1.4>COMMON PROCEDURES</PR1.4>
         <PR1.5>198809081123</PR1.5>
      </PR1>
      <ROL>
         <ROL.1>
            <EI.1>45</EI.1>
            <EI.2>RECORDER</EI.2>
            <EI.3>ROLE MASTER LIST</EI.3>
         </ROL.1>
         <ROL.2>AD</ROL.2>
         <ROL.3>
            <CWE.1>CP</CWE.1>
         </ROL.3>
         <ROL.4>
            <XCN.1>KATE</XCN.1>
            <XCN.2>
               <FN.1>SMITH</FN.1>
            </XCN.2>
            <XCN.3>ELLEN</XCN.3>
         </ROL.4>
         <ROL.5>199505011201</ROL.5>
      </ROL>
   </ADT_A01.PROCEDURE>
   <GT1>
      <GT1.1>1122</GT1.1>
      <GT1.2>
         <CX.1>1519</CX.1>
      </GT1.2>
      <GT1.3>
         <XPN.1>
            <FN.1>BILL</FN.1>
         </XPN.1>
         <XPN.2>GATES</XPN.2>
         <XPN.3>A</XPN.3>
      </GT1.3>
   </GT1>
   <ADT_A01.INSURANCE>
      <IN1>
         <IN1.1>001</IN1.1>
         <IN1.2>
            <CWE.1>A357</CWE.1>
         </IN1.2>
         <IN1.3>
            <CX.1>1234</CX.1>
         </IN1.3>
         <IN1.4>
            <XON.1>BCMD</XON.1>
         </IN1.4>
         <IN1.9>
            <XON.1>132987</XON.1>
         </IN1.9>
      </IN1>
      <IN2>
         <IN2.1>
            <CX.1>ID1551001</CX.1>
         </IN2.1>
         <IN2.2>SSN12345678</IN2.2>
      </IN2>
   </ADT_A01.INSURANCE>
</ADT_A01>
```

Comment: Check the content of your XML, you may require a custom transformer.

Comment: by custom transformer do you mean java?

Comment: Please include the structure of the XML in your question, removing any sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

Warning 'Message encoding is not recognized' is thrown when encoding is not ER7 or XML as per following link:

http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/cobertura/ca.uhn.hl7v2.preparser.PreParser.html

I tried sending HL7 message using HAPI test panel, then encoding is ER7 and still I get warning. However, transformation to JSON is successful. So, I feel that you can ignore the warning.

Comment: Even I am ignoring the warning for now. Hopefully it should not break anything later.

Comment: What is your question?